# How to implement condition which checks if Intent is running or closed?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am closing an Intent automatically using this code

```
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
new java.util.Timer().schedule(
    new java.util.TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            finishActivity(1);
        }
    },
    10000
);
```

I want to implement a condition which check if Intent is in process/running or already closed ? I am using Voice Recognition Intent .

Comment: what is your intent. i think to you had wrong solution for your problem.

Comment: Voice Recognizer Intent

Answer (score 0):

`Intent` is not a process, it's just a message storage that is being sent to the Android system.

Android will take care of the content of the Intent and there's no way of knowing what it does with it.

It's also a one way thing, once you send it, there's no use for it anymore, unless you want to send it again.